# Backbone.history.start() throws a TypeError when r.js -o is used

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, r.js

When I run the r.js optimizer over my Backbone.js app, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

It appears in the middle of the Backbone.js section of the output.

I removed bits of code until I found out what was causing it, and it seems to be when I call `Backbone.history.start();`.

I've created a simple app to replicate the bug, which I've posted below. Basically, it creates a route and 'console.log's 'home'. It works fine when not optimized.

To optimize the app, I use:

```
node r.js -o app.build.js
```

from the /js folder.

I have Backbone.js 0.9.2, RequireJS 2.1.1, r.js 2.1.1

Has anyone come across this before? I'm still fairly new to Backbone.js/RequireJS, so hopefully it's just something stupid I'm doing wrong.

### Folder Structure

```
/js
  /libs
    - backbone.js
    - require.js
    - underscore.js
  - app.build.js
  - r.js
  - site.js
index.html
```

### Code

#### index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <script data-main="/js/site.js" src="/js/libs/require.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

#### site.js

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl     : 'js/',
    paths       : {
        jquery          : '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min',
        backbone        : 'libs/backbone',
        underscore      : 'libs/underscore'
    },
    shim        : {
        backbone        : {
            deps            : ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports         : 'Backbone'
        },
        underscore      : {
            exports         : '_'
        }
    }
});

require(['jquery', 'backbone'], function($, Backbone) {

    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
            routes      : {
                ''          : 'home'
            },
            home        : function(){
                console.log('home');
            }
        }),
        appRouter;

    $(function() {

        appRouter = new Router();
        Backbone.history.start();

    });

});
```

#### app.build.js

```
({
    baseUrl: ".",
    name: 'site',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'empty:',
        underscore: 'libs/underscore',
        backbone: 'libs/backbone'
    },
    out: 'site-built.js',
    shim        : {
        backbone        : {
            deps            : ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports         : 'Backbone'
        },
        underscore      : {
            exports         : '_'
        }
    }
})
```

Thanks!

### Update

Here's the output of site-built.js. Can anyone see anything obviously wrong with it?

http://pastebin.com/Rbm7J83X

Comment: I know this isn't helpful for you, but it works perfectly fine for me with the code you have provided :s

Comment: Cheers, must be something specific to my computer then. I'll try it on a different machine and see what happens.

Comment: I already had some WTF with the optimizer, if i remember well it was an invisible character on a end of line. Manually retyping the line, the one before and the one after fixed it.

Comment: I've got sublime to strip all the trailing spaces out, so there shouldn't be any hidden characters. I moved some lines about, but no joy. I've just updated the question with the output of my optimised file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inlined jQuery and it seems to work OK now. (It's mentioned at the bottom of the [API shim docs on requirejs.org](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim), but not anywhere on the Optimize section.)

Not sure if this is the correct fix, but hopefully it will help someone else.